# Api Base URL for Bitcoin Cash

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash

I have Successfully integrated **Bitcoin** To get payment so to verify Transaction from given address, I use 
`https://blockchain.info/multiaddr?active=$address|$address`
, which is working for **Bitcoin**.

So now I want to integrate **Bitcoin Cash**. For **Bitcoin cash** what is the base URL from *blockchain.info*.

I search for this many places. I am not able to find a solution.

Plz suggest me to integrate for test net for bitcoin cash too.

Comment: Blockchain info doesn't have a Bitcoin Cash API.

Comment: Hello manoj, are you find any api for Bitcoin cash, if you find, please tell me which is you are using for Bitcoin cash

Comment: @rajanasekhar I am using bitcoincashjs library for bitcoin cash which supports test net, I am writing solution for this on answer section :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bitcoincashjs` Library

```
const bitcore = require('bitcoincashjs');

const HdPublicKey = new bitcore.HDPublicKey.fromString(xpubKey);
            const derivedPublicKey = HdPublicKey.derive("m/0/" + index).publicKey;
            const address = derivedPublicKey.toAddress();
            requestObj.BCHAddress = address.toString();
```

to verify Transaction use `blocktrail-sdk`

```
const blocktrail = require('blocktrail-sdk');
const client = blocktrail.BlocktrailSDK({
    apiKey: apiKey,
    apiSecret: apiSecret,
    network: "BCC",
    testnet: false
});
```

then you can call many function of `client` like

```
    client.addressTransactions(bitAddress[i].BCHAddress,
     async function (err, addressTxs) {
         //Code here 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these. I think this may help you.

https://github.com/owstack/bch-explorer-api

https://bch.btc.com/api-doc

Comment: Hi, these are not working for Bitcoin Cash

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use separate URL for that.

https://bitcoincash.blockexplorer.com/